# How to boot and read a Windows 9X boot CD from a 2TB SCSI/NVMe SSD?

Tags: boot, ssd, ms-dos, floppy, windows-98

First I want to apologize that I thought it was SCSI, that's what the Device manager details told me. I tried to boot both a Windows 98 SE and a (patched) Windows ME Boot Disk equipped SSD, and it booted it both on a real PC and on VMWare with the same results (I will be showing the results of VMWare).

It booted successfully.

The problem is that right after boot, it stops being able to read from the SSD asking for a directory with a command interpreter:

[image: Screenshot]

When I redirect to the floppy entering `A:\command.com`, it doesn't matter whether I put the Win98 files on the SSD or the WinME ones. It says it isn't ready reading from the SSD I just booted from:

[image: Screenshot 2]

When I try to enter any command with SSD Root as cd, I get prompted with the following question and enter `F:`

[image: Screenshot 3]

As you can see, the `cd` command gives me the `Fail on INT 24` error. If I enter an invalid command, I get prompted the same question without the int 24 error, but with a `Bad command or file name` error instead.

The SSD is formatted in FAT32 as it should and connected via the supported SCSI (Edit: Device Manager lied. It's NVMe and is not supported as of VMware). Do I need a LBA48 driver/patch for the emergency boot disk?

It worked with a 2000MB partition instead of 128000MB, but that was fat16. Windows 10 can't get past the 32gb limit, "fat32 format" doesn't support SSD and some other programs have this functionality only in the paid version. There happens to be a Seagate Samsung Disk utility, but it only works on external drives. I found another Seagate DiscWizard utility. It looks like it's formatted successfully, but it gives the following error on boot:

```
Non-system disk, press any key...
MBR Error 1
Press any key to boot from floppy...
```

Comment: please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/230282). And this is likely off-topic here anyway

Comment: but they're for related questions and not for retro systems

Comment: JeremyP from Retrocomputing suggested to try it on a partition smaller first, so I'll create a 137 GB primary with Windows 10 first.

Comment: Both formatting a 128000 MB drive didn't work, I'll try 2gb than (2000MB).

Comment: 2GB worked for me, I'm may remove the question on retro computing.

Comment: @KevinCrans It's good to see you got a solution! When you expand, please do so in the answer box below; that way, you can actually mark it as "solved" by accepting your answer.

Comment: Yeah, they don't accept answers from my account anymore, thank you for your response, I've seen cases where the problem was EMM386.exe though. Wish Windows ME boot-disks supported that for gaming, but don't think that was my issue since I also tried 98 before.